# How to run SQL Server Stored Procedure from Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures

I am trying to run a SQL Server Stored Procedure from Excel. I have the following code which runs with no error in Excel but does not seem to do anything in SQL Server.

```
<Run on>
excel: office 365 ( web )
sql server 2008


Sub Bld_Eol_Bom_Data()

   Dim sqlStatement As String
   sqlStatement = "EXECUTE dbo.bld_eol_bom ;"
   Debug.Print sqlStatement
   With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("hhi-t-sql05-eSearch").OLEDBConnection.CommandText = sqlStatement
   End With
   ActiveWorkbook.Connections("hhi-t-sql05-eSearch").Refresh

End Sub
```

The SP populates a table in SQL Server. If I run the SP in SSMS it works. But when I run the above in Excel it does not populate the table.

Also how can I check the the connection is setup correctly and working?